# Can't compile document because of the geometry package

Tags: packages, margins, undefined

Whenever I try to compile a document containing the `geometry` package, no matter how simple it may be, I always get an error message. I've never had this problem before.

Code:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

Error message:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
> \Gm@detectdriver ...driver: auto-detecting}\ifpdf
> \ifx \pdfextension @undef...
> l.4 \begin{document}
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
> of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
> misspelled it (e.g., '\hobx'), type 'I' and the correct
> spelling (e.g., 'I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> ! Extra \fi.

Comment: Can you show your complete .log file?

Comment: Works fine for me on a current texsystem. You probably have outdated packages.

Comment: Not the problem, but `14pt` does not exist by default

Comment: No problem here either on an up to date TeXLive 2019. My guess: you're on miktex. Please make sure to update miktex in both miktex user mode and miktex admin mode. Additionally you'll probably need to manually update the package list before that. It is all in the menus of the miktex console programme.

Comment: is that the _first_ error or did you get an earlier error about a missing ifpdf.sty file?

Comment: Possibly related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527315/how-to-fix-miktex-compiler-driver-has-stopped-working

Answer (score -1):

---

I have reinstalled `MikTeX 2.9` and updated it many times. But I still get a similar error:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

> (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-dvips.def)
> No file geo.aux.
> *geometry* driver: auto-detecting
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> \Gm@detectdriver ...driver: auto-detecting}\ifpdf
> \ifx \pdfextension >@undef...
> l.4 \begin{document}

Comment: You should post another question instead post an answer here.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please post your own.